# My Application is not working after added custom behavior, cant understand why

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have created a custom stepper Behavior, and added that behavior to a stepper in my xaml, but for some reason after adding the behavior the application doesn't compile, and i get this error:

```
Position 82:87. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'ValueChangedCommand', or mismatching type between value and property. (ComanderoMovil)
```

here is my code of the behavior:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ComanderoMovil.Behaviors
{
    public class StepperQuantityChangedBehavior : Behavior<Stepper>
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty StepperValueChangedProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("ValueChangedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(StepperQuantityChangedBehavior), null);

        public ICommand ValueChangedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return (ICommand)GetValue(StepperValueChangedProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(StepperValueChangedProperty, value);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Stepper bindable)
        {
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
            bindable.ValueChanged += Bindable_ValueChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Stepper bindable)
        {
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
            bindable.ValueChanged -= Bindable_ValueChanged;
        }

        private void Bindable_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ValueChangedCommand == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var stepper = sender as Stepper;
            var prueba = e.NewValue;

            if (ValueChangedCommand.CanExecute(prueba))
            {
                ValueChangedCommand.Execute(prueba);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my code of the xaml where I add the behavior:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ComanderoMovil.Views.DishView"
             xmlns:converterPack="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.ConvertersPack;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.ConvertersPack"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComanderoMovil.Behaviors"
             x:Name="DishSelectedPage">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Icon="shopping_cart" Text="Search"  Command="{Binding ShowCartCommand}" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

     <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converterPack:CurrencyConverter x:Key="CurrencyConverter"></converterPack:CurrencyConverter>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Dish.Name}"
                       FontSize="Title"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                <Label Text="Precio"
                       FontSize="Subtitle"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                <Label Text="{Binding Dish.Price1, Converter={StaticResource CurrencyConverter}}"
                       FontSize="Subtitle"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
                <Label Text="Modificadores"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       FontSize="Large"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DishesMods}"
                          x:Name="ModsListView"
                          HasUnevenRows="True"
                          SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                          SeparatorColor="Black"
                          IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                          HeightRequest="{Binding ListHeight}">
                    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell Height="30">
                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                             Padding="10"
                                             BackgroundColor="DimGray">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Key}"
                                           TextColor="White"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Padding="20">
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <CheckBox Color="#102536">
                                            <CheckBox.Behaviors>
                                                <local:CheckBoxModChangedState ItemCheckedCommand="{Binding BindingContext.SelectedModCommand, Source={Reference DishSelectedPage}}"></local:CheckBoxModChangedState>
                                            </CheckBox.Behaviors>
                                        </CheckBox>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                               VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                                        <Label Text="Precio:"
                                               VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Price}"
                                               VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Label Text="Cantidad: "></Label>
                                        <Label Text="1"></Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Stepper HeightRequest="40"
                                                 WidthRequest="40">
                                            <Stepper.Behaviors>
                                                <local:StepperQuantityChangedBehavior ValueChangedCommand="{Binding BindingContext.ModQuantityCommand, Source={Reference DishSelectedPage}}"></local:StepperQuantityChangedBehavior>
                                            </Stepper.Behaviors>
                                        </Stepper>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListView.Footer>
                        <ContentView>
                            <Frame HasShadow="False"
                                   Padding="50">
                                <Button Padding="20"
                                        Text="Agregar Orden"
                                        TextColor="White"
                                        BackgroundColor="#102536"
                                        Command="{Binding BindingContext.AddOrderCommand, Source={Reference DishSelectedPage}}"></Button>
                            </Frame>
                        </ContentView>
                    </ListView.Footer>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

the funny thing is that,  I have added custom behavior for other controls, like the checkbox, and it works without a problem, but only with this new behavior I am having trouble.

Anyone know's what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static readonly BindableProperty StepperValueChangedProperty
public ICommand ValueChangedCommand
```

the issue is on the lines,as the error message said

> event found for 'ValueChangedCommand', or mismatching type between
>   value and property. (ComanderoMovil)

you should change `StepperValueChangedProperty` to `ValueChangedCommandProperty` to keep the name consistent with `ValueChangedCommand`

change

```
public static readonly BindableProperty StepperValueChangedProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ValueChangedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(StepperQuantityChangedBehavior), null);

    public ICommand ValueChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)GetValue(StepperValueChangedProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(StepperValueChangedProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

to

```
  public static readonly BindableProperty ValueChangedCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ValueChangedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(StepperQuantityChangedBehavior), null);

    public ICommand ValueChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)GetValue(ValueChangedCommandProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ValueChangedCommandProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this was the solution!!, So the naming is important in behaviors case, thanks a lot